# Combobox Render with optional params

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am solving a requirement which can be simplified as following. I am fairly new to Ext.js and I need help in achieving the below.

I have 4 tables as follows.

[image]

So, I have 3000 companies and 9000 users mapped across various companies. I need to map moderators for each company in a grid.

I have an add button, which adds a row in the grid.

I achieved displaying the companies in the first column of a grid. Easy. So user can pick one.

I achieved displaying users belonging to that company in the second column of the grid. FYI, User can multi select moderators here.

Problem:
**At this point, when I add a new row, pick a new company, the companyusers store gets refreshed, so, the values selected in 1st row are not valid values anymore and the first row's user column is displaying empty text (or) only the id's**

My models are as follows

```
Ext.define('Mine.CompanyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['Id', {name: 'Name', type:'string'}]});

Ext.define('Mine.UsersModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['Id', {name: 'Name', type:'string'}]});

Ext.define('Mine.CompanyUsersModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['company_user_id', 'UserName']}); //<companyuser Id>

Ext.define('Mine.CompanyModeratorModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['Id', 'CompanyUserId']});
```

My stores are

```
Ext.define('Mine.CompanyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Mine.CompanyModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Data'
        }
    })
});

Ext.define('Mine.UsersStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Mine.UsersModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Data'
        }
    }),
}); 

Ext.define('Mine.CompanyUserStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Mine.CompanyUserModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Data'
        }
    }),
    //will add extra params here
});

Ext.define('Mine.CompanyModeratorStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Mine.CompanyModeratorModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Data'
        }
    }),

});
```

My grid columns are

```
{
     text: 'Company', width: '10%', dataIndex: 'id',
     renderer: companyRenderer(combo_company), editor: combo_company
 },
 {
     text: 'Users', width: '16%', dataIndex: 'company_user_id',
     renderer: companyUsersRenderer(companyUsersCbo), editor: companyUsersCbo
 }
```

My editor is

```
var companyUsersCbo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
             xtype: 'combo',
             id: 'company_users',
             name: 'company_users',
             valueField: 'Id',
             displayField: 'name',
             allowBlank: false,
             store: 'Mine.CompanyUsersStore',
             multiSelect: false,
             editable: true,
             queryMode: 'local',
             pickerAlign: 'bl',
             listConfig: {
                 getInnerTpl: function (display) {
                     return '<div class="x-combo-list-item"><img src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '" class="chkCombo-default-icon chkCombo" /> {' + display + '} </div>';
                 }
             }
             listeners: {
                 expand: function () {
                     var mainGrid = Ext.getCmp('mygrid');
                     var selmodel = mainGrid.getSelectionModel();
                     var record = selmodel.getSelection();
                     if (record[0].get('id') != null) {
                         this.getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam('company_id', record[0].get('id')); // am storing the company id in a model
                         this.getStore().load();
                     }
                 }
             }
        });
```

My renderer is

```
        var companyUsersRenderer = function (combo) {
        return function (resources) {
             var result = [];
             resources = resources || [];
             for (var idx = 0, len = resources.length; idx < len; idx++) {
                 var value = combo.getStore().find(combo.valueField, resources[idx]);
                 if (value != -1) {
                     var rec = combo.getStore().getAt(value);
                     result.push(rec.get(combo.displayField));
                 }
             }
             return result.join(', ');
         }
    }
```

What am I missing? What should I do so that the values (names) displayed in the combo box remain independent of the next rows.

What have I tried:: I have added a separate hidden column and set it to the names, added to the record. It worked fine, but its not the correct way. Also, when I double click the cell for editing, it shows the numbers (id's and not text) but after I expand, it shows the text.

Comment: widgetcolumns are standard way of using other components (like combo) inside a grid. Try using them : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html

Comment: Please provide example with jsfiddle

Comment: As @avinash told, a working fiddle or code snippet will help to understand the issue. I have 2 questions, why you are reloading grid store instead of reloading combo store on expand and why you have same `CompanyModel` for both `CompanyStore` & ` CompanyStore`.

Comment: Hi @ankitchaudhary, 1) I am reloading the combo store. Checked it. The scoping refers to the combobox in this case. And 2) It is just a typo. It must be UserModel for UserStore

Answer (score 1):

naga Sandeep,
    try to send params with your URL to get filtered records.

```
like,
url:'someThing/abc/1435'+'id='+record.id;

filter your store accordingly.
```

Comment: Problem is, each row has its own filterring and thus, records. After second row is fitered, first row is not displaying its records.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is when your grid is rendered, your columns are rendered and your render function uses last state of the combo's store.

I would add a display field to CompanyUsersModel then fill it when a company is selected. Also I would abandon renderer function.